# How to show lower and upper bound (errorbar, candlesticks etc.) in Matplotlib and classify by category?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot 3 attributes, ['outdoor temp', 'outdoor temp low', 'outdoor temp high'] in my dataframe against ['humidity'].

I'd then like to colour each plot given it's corresponding category 'month' in the same data frame. (I was able to do this using Hue in seaborn's facetgrid plot, however then not sure how to do these errorbars).

Achieving this by using plt.errorbars has been an issue as I want to explicitly pass the upper and lower bound of my x (or y values).

Perhaps I could do multiple (line) plots? Any ideas?

Example of the kind of plot I'm looking to achieve below:
[image: Errorbars in matplotlib]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pyplot.errorbar` can take lists of lists as input, if what you want is asymmetrical errorbars: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/errorbar_features.html